# jQTouch Photo Gallery Questions

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

Hey guys, im using here the jqTouch gallery extension and im having some issues.First of all, i setted a Photo gallery on my index. But i need a Horizontal scroller too. How can i activate the horizontal scroller?

Thanks!